# Predict next element of a sequence

Tags: c#

I was not exactly sure how to ask this so here goes:

I have a database with some sequences of single characters on it, like ABAB, CA, CDABD, and so on. And I'm trying to create something in C# where I would write a character and it would suggest me the next character based on existing sequences on the database. And everytime I write one more character the suggestion changes accordingly.

I have a C# application connected to the database and I can retrieve the data, but I have no clue what structure to use for this and what's the best way to do it, I'm lost..

Can someone suggest me something to work with this? I have been searching but it hasn't been easy.

EDIT: Forgot about the most important part. If the input doesn't match any of the sequences on the database, the program should suggest the most probable sequence (for example, if the user inputs one character wrong). Don't know if I'm being clear enough..

Comment: What is the logic behind which suggestion should show?

If I have ABBA, ABBB AAAA and type "A" which record would be suggested?

Comment: @SEarle1986 it can return all of them and I'll process them later. The input will almost always be a larger set of characters and the results will be two or three at max

Comment: So you're basically looking for `select value from sequences where value like 'A%'`?

Comment: @rene Please check my edit!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by "I have no clue what structure to use" - you presumably just get strings back from the database and can then manipulate them to get the next character after what you already have entered... What are you thinking you need complicated structures for? I'm a little confused by what exactly you are having problems with...

Comment: @Chris I need to process each character individually to see if the user made mistakes and calculate the most probable sequence to correct it!

Comment: @tiago32: Could you just refuse to let them enter a letter that doesn't make a valid sequence? ie treat it as a validation exercise rather than an error correction exercise?

Comment: @Chris I can't, I really need to search the most probable sequence and attempt to correct it, that's what is making it so hard

Comment: @tiago32: If the user doesn't know to enter the correct sequence in the first place how will they know which of the suggested corrections is the right one (if there are more than one)? You might just end up with them choosing a valid but wrong sequence rather than the valid but right one that you want them to. This doesn't feel like it solves any problems (though I may be wrong)

Comment: To provide some vaguely useful thoughts though you may be able to use some kind of spell check component with a custom dictionary that contains your list of valid values. This might allow you to get suggestions of valid sequences close to the ones entered.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting task got me thinking about "cool" ways how to solve the suggesting part. I'm pretty sure you could use some graph theory for it, but having forgotten most of it, I can't really remember exactly what you could use.

What I thought about then is a n-dimensional array of bits where n is the length of the longest string in your database. Then every dimension has a length of the required character set (+1, will explain later). In that space you then construct a mapping of your database so that every dimension of your array is a certain position in the given "word". If you have shorter strings than n, you use the 0 as a index in all remaining dimensions (basically saying that 3 letters don't have a mapping in 4 dimensions) - that's the +1 to length btw. You could even easily find there are results in higher dimensions than you're currently at giving you the "predict next letters" ability.

If you stop adding more letters, the task to find the best suggestion then would be to traverse all dimensions and check what's the smallest amount dimension indices that you would have to change to find a "hit".

I'm pretty sure this is slow and memory demanding AF, you can boil down the idea to much more compact structures than my naive example. (Basically a dictionary and just checking how many letters you have to change to find a "hit" is basically the same idea) but I love to think in high dimensional space. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's little detail in you question about user interface etc but here is a method which will accept the search string and return the results as a DataSet. This meets the

> it can return all of them and I'll process them later. The input will
>   almost always be a larger set of characters and the results will be
>   two or three at max

criteria in your comment

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

private DataSet GetSuggestions(string searchTerm)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
       SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 YourColumn FROM YourTable WHERE YourField LIKE '@term%' ORDER BY SomeColumn", con);
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("term", searchTerm);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();

        return ds;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please see my edit on the question!

Comment: So again, given ABBA, ABBB AAAA and the user types "B", how do you define which is the most probable?